# seemingly spurious error message for unhandled exception

Tags: java, java-stream

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.util.List;
public class CSVIO
{
    //read a file and return a list of records in the file
    public static List<String[]> read(File f) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        List<String[]> out = br.lines()
                               .map( e -> e.split(","))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return out;

    }
    //write from a list of recrords into CSV format
    public static void write(List<String[]> items, File dest) throws IOException
    {
        //return true if it successfully writes.
            final BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dest));
            items.stream()
                 .map( row -> String.join(",",  row))
                 .forEach( row  -> bw.write(row + "\n"));
    }
}
```

I get this error message when I run:

```
$ javac CSVIO.java
CSVIO.java:29: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                 .forEach( row  -> bw.write(row + "\n"));
                                           ^
1 error
```

I have properly declared that the write method throws an exception.
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You have to catch that exception in your `.forEach()`.

Comment: your _lambda_ throws the exception... via `row  -> bw.write`. besides the de-tour you have is weird, just use `Files::lines` for example

Comment: Doesn't Files::lines just create a stream for reading?   Isn't it a source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your `br.write()` throws the exception. You have to catch that in your lambda expression (`.forEach()`):

```
items.stream()
     .map(row -> String.join(",",  row))
     .forEach( row  -> {
         try {
             bw.write(row + "\n");
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     });
```

But you can just shorten this using [`Files.write()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-):

```
public static void write(List<String[]> items, Path path) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = items.stream()
            .map(row -> String.join(",", row))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Files.write(path, lines);
}
```

You also can simplify your `read` method using [`Files.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-):

```
public static List<String[]> read(Path path) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
        return lines
                .map(e -> e.split(","))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a super-nice answer.  I had a vague suspicion the lambda might be the culprit.

Comment: Or `Files.write(path, () -> items.stream() .<CharSequence>map(row -> String.join(",", row)) .iterator());`

Comment: @Holger What is the advantage of this?

Comment: It doesn’t populate a `List<String>` with all lines before even starting to write. And it’s just one statement instead of two.